# Grease Pencil: Python script to create a line connects to origin

Tags: scripting, grease-pencil

I am writing a script that draws a grease pencil line between two points. While the script draws the line, strangely enough, it also connects the line to the origin. Here is the script:

```
# create gp data
gpencil_data = bpy.data.grease_pencils.new("Gpencil")

# create a gp object and add it to collection
gpencil = bpy.data.objects.new(gpencil_data.name, gpencil_data)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(gpencil)

gp_layer = gpencil_data.layers.new("lines") # add a gp layer

gp_frame = gp_layer.frames.new(20) # add a gp frame

gp_stroke = gp_frame.strokes.new() # add a gp stroke
gp_stroke.line_width = 40
gp_stroke.use_cyclic = False

gp_stroke.points.add(count=4)   
gp_stroke.points[0].co = (-1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
gp_stroke.points[1].co = (1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
```

This is how the output looks:
[image]

I can't figure out why its connecting to the origin. Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change `gp_stroke.points.add(count=4)` into `gp_stroke.points.add(count=2)` and your problem is gone with the wind.

You probably understand why: when you add 4 points and only set the first two, `gp_stroke.points[2].co` and `gp_stroke.points[3].co` are initialized at (0, 0, 0) – which happens to be the origin...

Comment: Thank you! This answers my question. And thanks to your explanation, it does seem obvious now :)